# LinearModelFit[] of simulated data

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to simulate Hooke's law, f = k * x, so I generate data with the code:

```
m = 70;  
k = 150.62; 
l = 23.407;  
d = OpenWrite["data.dat", FormatType -> OutputForm];  
table = Table[p = RandomInteger[100000];  
              If[EvenQ[p], e = 1, e = -1];  
              g = e*500.*RandomReal[1.];  
              {x = l*RandomReal[1.], f = k*x + g},  
              {i, m}];  
Export[d, table, "Table"]  
Close[d]  
recta = LinearModelFit[tabla, x, x];  
Normal[recta]
```

I have a question before running this code.  Would I obtain the same if I choose

```
p=RandomInteger[10]?
```

What I want is that not all of the points "fall" on the straight line so I put "noise" g to the force. 
The data is well generated and checking the file "data.dat", everything is there. But I obtain the message:

```
LinearModelFit::ivar: "{11.2833} is not a valid variable."
```

I'm stuck. Can you help me?

Comment: I don't understand your data generation routine. But if you change your last two lines by `recta = LinearModelFit[table, u, u]; Normal@recta;` it works

Comment: @belisarius I see what he was trying to get at. Not that I've come up with a better title, yet.

Comment: Could you choose a descriptive title for your question?  Just click on the edit link above to make changes.

Comment: @rcollyer Well, I still can't figure it out :)

Comment: @belisarius well, look at my answer. I think it explains it.

Comment: addressing your random selection procedure, the range `0-100000` contains 50,000 odds and 50,001 evens, so your selection is slightly biased to the evens. If you made the range 10 it would be significantly biased. Assuming you don't want any bias you should do simply `e=RandomChoice[{-1, 1}]` or better still `g=500 RandomReal[{-1,1}]`

Comment: One possible title: "How do I simulate raw data (with measurement error) from a known function?"

Comment: Ironically this must be one of the most vague subject headings the site has to offer.

Answer (score 4):

There are quite a few things going on with your code, and not all of them sanguine.

First, you open a stream to use `Export` which is not necessary. While `Export` is perfectly happy to work this way, it will also handle the opening and closing of streams for you if you just pass it the file name, like

```
Export["data.dat", table, "Table"]
```

By using it the way you do, you open yourself up to resource leaks, where the stream remains open if you `Abort` execution.

Second, your data generation has several issues. The largest is your use of global variables, `p`, `e`, `g`, `x`, and `f`. This is what is causing the message since `x` has a value. So, you need to isolate them, and I'd prefer to use `Block` here.  Additionally, except for `x` you don't need any other variables, including the `Table` iterator `i`. Here's the simplified code:

```
table = Table[
  Block[{x},
    {x = l*RandomReal[1.],k*x + RandomReal[{-500, 500}]}
  ]
  ,  
  {m}
];
```

Lastly, you have a typo this

```
recta = LinearModelFit[tabla, x, x];
```

should be

```
recta = LinearModelFit[table, x, x];
```

Comment: Hi rcollyer. Thanks for the answer. I corrected my code and had to change x --> t in: LinearModelFit[table,t,t] because, even using Block[ ], I was receiving the same message.

Comment: you need to restart the kernel after making that change.

Comment: @AntonioOrtiz George is correct. You were still operating within the same session, so either restart the kernel or run `Clear[x]`.